# I change the min and max of the xaxis, but how to i change the 'navigator'?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am leveraging Highcharts' HighStock "chart" to display some information.
I update a my series, and update the xAxis min and max value, but it seems that the scope remains for the navigator.

I was looking through the documentation and didnt see a means in which to reset the slider to whatever the min-max are?

```
this.chartOptions.xAxis[0].min = fromTime * 1000;
this.chartOptions.xAxis[0].max = toTime * 1000;
this.chartOptions.series = [];
/// ...
/// gets data set.
/// ...
this.update = true;
```

This sets the ranges, where fromtime and totime are datetimes, but to the second, so i needed to adjust accordingly.  I didnt see any other key properties which made immediately recognize the xAxis' slide bar scope/zoom.

When i was looking up the navigator information, I was noticing that the default of it should be `adaptToUpdatedData: true`.  It seems that each time after the second will not update the navigator though. Not sure why it allows 1 resize to be correct, but subsequent are not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Fold answer.

First of all, you need to use the setExtremes function and not explicitly set the min and max.  You should have a variable referencing highcharts.

```
highcharts = Highcharts;
```

for example in your component.  The next thing you need to is call:

```
this.highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].setExtremes(fromTime * 1000, toTime * 1000);
```

but there is also 1 other issue.  First of all, this is with the expectation that you are only rendering 1 chart at a time, as this monitors all charts in memory.  I have 5, so you need to make sure you have the right one.

To do this, you need to assign a unique identifier to the chart.

```
private _guid: Guid
chartOptions :any = {}

constructor(){ 
  this._guid = Guid.newGuid(); 
  this.chartOptions.guid = this._guid;
}
```

Now, you may think, Guid isnt a thing. You are correct.  You would want to implement that.  I would search Stack overflow for a good implementation.

Now that you have a guid for your chart.

```
getChart() => this.highcharts.filter( chart => chart["userOptions"].guid == this._guid)[0];
```

and now you have the correct chart.

You can then change your variables as needed.

```
getChart().xAxis[0].setExtremes(a,b);
```

It will all come together as such:

```
export class testComponnt implemented OnInit {
  chartOptions = {};  //StockChart specific options.
  private _guid: Guid;
  highcharts = Highcharts;
  getChart() => this.highcharts.charts.filter( chart => chart["userOptions"].guid == this._guid)[0];
  constructor(){
    this._guid = Guid.newGuid();
    this.chartOptions.guid = this._guid;
  }

  updateData() {
    let chart = getChart();
    if (!chart) return;
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes( fromTime * 1000, toTime * 1000 );
    this.chartOptions.series = [];
    //  data manipulation here.
    this.update = true;
  }
}
```